# Prove that this sequence is convergent by using the limit definition

Tags: limits

Suppose I have the following sequence:

$ a_n = \frac{2n -\sqrt (n^2+1)}{ n+cos(n)}$

The definition says that for each $\epsilon > 0 $ there exists a positive integer $n_0 $ such that for all n > $n_0 : |a_n - L | < \epsilon$

Before starting to prove this I try to find a value for $ n_0 $ in function of $ \epsilon $.

We can write that:

$ a_n = \frac{2n - \sqrt (n^2+1)}{ n+cos(n)} \leq \frac{2n}{ n+cos(n)} $

But then I am stuck with the $ cos(n) $ in the denominator.

My idea was to use the fact that the cosine is always between -1 and 1.

Thus, $ cos(n) \leq 1 $ and $ a_n = \frac{2n - \sqrt (n^2+1)}{ n+cos(n)} \leq \frac{2n}{ n+cos(n)} \leq \frac{2n}{ n+1} \leq \frac{2n}{ n} \leq 2 $

But then again I am stuck because this doesn't help me to find an $ n_0 $ in function of $ \epsilon $

EDIT:

@TheSilverDoe reminded me that I forgot the '-L' part in the definition.

I have to calculate the limit first:

Write:

$ \frac{2n - \sqrt (n^2+1)}{ n +1} \leq \frac{2n - \sqrt (n^2)}{ n+1} \leq \frac{2n - \sqrt (n^2+1)}{ n+cos(n)} \leq\frac{2n - \sqrt (n^2)}{ n-1} \leq\frac{2n - \sqrt (n^2+1)}{ n-1} $

or

$ \frac{n}{ n+1} \leq \frac{2n - \sqrt (n^2+1)}{ n+cos(n)}  \leq\frac{n}{ n-1} $

From that we can easily see that the limit is equal to 1.

Back to my original question we have:

$ a_n - L = \frac{2n - \sqrt (n^2+1)}{ n+cos(n)} - 1 \leq \frac{2n}{ n+cos(n)} - 1 \leq \frac{2n}{ n+1} - 1 \leq \frac{2n}{ n} - 1 \leq 2 - 1 = 1$

This brings me back to the same question I had originally

Comment: If you want to prove the convergence using the definition of the limit, you have to know what is the limit...

Comment: Right, I forgot the - L part. So I guess that would be the first step? Finding the limit?

Comment: Yes, you have to "guess" what the limit is. And then, prove that for this value of $L$, the definition of convergence is satisfied. (Actually in that case, it is quite weird because you can find the limit directly, and skip the use of the definition of the limit.)

Comment: Is the limit here equal to 2?

Comment: No. Roughly speaking, $\sqrt{n^2+1}$ is almost $\sqrt{n^2}=n$, so the numerator is almost $n$. And the denominator is also almost $n$ since the $\cos$ is bounded whereas the $n$ becomes very large. So the limit will be $n/n = 1$. If you know asymptotic expansions, you can solve this limit very quickly, just formalizing what I just said.

Comment: I don't know about asymptotic expansions but I solved the limit ( see my EDIT ) with the squeeze theorem

Comment: You've got the following chain the other way round, $$\frac{n}{ n-1} \leq \frac{2n - \sqrt (n^2+1)}{ n+cos(n)}  \leq\frac{n}{ n+1}$$ since $$\frac{n}{n-1} \ge \frac{n}{n+1}$$ because bigger denominator implies smaller fraction. The line before should thus change as $$n-1 \le n+\cos(n) \le n+1 \implies \dfrac1{n+1} \le \dfrac1{n+\cos(n)} \le \dfrac1{n-1}$$

Comment: That's right, thanks. My question still holds though

Comment: It doesn't help you to show that $a_n \le 2$ (or $\le 3$ or $\le 35436$) unless you can get *close* to the $2$.  And as $\sqrt{n^2 + 1} > n$ then $2n  -\sqrt{n^2 + 1} < 2n - n =n$ you cant really.  But we could do $\frac {n-1}{n+1}=\frac{2n-\sqrt{n^2 + 2n+1}}{n+1}< a_n < \frac{2n-\sqrt{n^2}}{n-1} = \frac {n}{n-1}$.  We also $\frac {n-1}{n+1} < 1 < \frac n{n-1}$ so $|1-a_n|< |\frac {n}{n-1}-\frac {n-1}{n+1}|=\frac {3n+1}{n^2-1}<\frac {3n+1}{n^2+\frac 13n}=\frac 3n$  so let $n_0 = \frac 3\epsilon$.

Comment: You can't really brush away $\sqrt{n^2 + 1} > n$ as "insignificant".  Yes, $2$ is an upper limit but but so is $57 \times 10^{google}$.  If we were comparing $\sqrt{n^2+1}$ to $n^2$ or if we were "brushing away" a constant compared to $n$ that'd be okay.  In terms of "brushing" away the $1$ compared to $n^2$ is insignificant and then $\cos n$ is insignificant to $n$ so $a_n =\frac {2n-\sqrt{n^2+1}}{n+\cos n} \approx \frac {2n-\sqrt{n^2}}n = \frac {2n-n}n =\frac nn =1$.  So the limit *ought* to be $1$. But "brushing off the insignificant" is not valid or rigorous enough for grown-ups.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't help you to show that $a_n \le 2$ (or $\le 3$ or $\le 35436$) unless you can get *close* to the $2$.  And as $\sqrt{n^2 + 1} > n$ then $2n  -\sqrt{n^2 + 1} < 2n - n =n$ you cant really get close to $2$.

But we could do $\frac {n-1}{n+1}=\frac {2n-(n+1)}{n+1} = \frac{2n-\sqrt{n^2 + 2n+1}}{n+1}<\frac {2n-\sqrt{n^2+1}}{n+\cos n}= a_n < \frac{2n-\sqrt{n^2}}{n-1} = \frac {n}{n-1}$.

We should just be able to *look* and $\frac {n-1}{n+1} \to 1$ and $\frac {n}{n-1}\to 1$ and use the squeeze theorem but... where's the fun in that?  Which is my tongue in check way of saying we'll never learn how to not fear delta epsilon proofs if we keep avoid them.

$\frac {n-1}{n+1} = 1-\frac 2{n+1} < 1 < 1 + \frac1{n-1} = \frac n{n-1}$.

So we have both $a_n$ and $1$ between the extremes of $\frac {n-1}{n+1}$ and $\frac n{n-1}$.

So $|1-a_n| < |\frac n{n-1} - \frac {n-1}{n+1}| = \frac 1{n-1} + \frac 2{n+1}< \frac 1{n-1} +\frac 2{n-1} = \frac 3{n-1}$.

So if we want $\frac 3{n-1} < \epsilon$ it is sufficient (more than sufficient) to have $\frac 3\epsilon < n-1$ so let $n_0 = \frac 3\epsilon +1$.